# Crashes of Classify function

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning, crash

I'm working on a classifying two classes. I am training my `Classify` function with the `RandomForest` method, but it crashes.
The size of training data is 2365819 examples as in the following code.

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "RandomForest"];

 trainingData = {{{0.2443901294459203`, 0.6339894544265186`, 0.348376166232641`, 
       0.6205766754715589`, 0.6949430713884377`, 0.09981477603065425`, 
       0.2652380125320035`, 0.7326739707331305`, 0.33572175175325736`, 
       0.15215974016395206`}, {0.40877022570675847`, 0.5013459204618054`, 
       0.18091097996572647`, 0.9841680784952942`, 0.46040777479106754`, 
       0.9721054020948912`, 0.7980120864921296`, 0.985753996194227`, 
       0.36559491598469984`, 0.2578547049404678`}} -> 0.0 
    {{0.033860045146726865`, 110.`, 3.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
       0.13636363636363635`, 0.9766334638696152`, 3.`, 
       1972.`}, {0.035211267605633804`, 177.`, 8.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
       0.0903954802259887`, 0.9766334638696152`, 3.`, 1145.`}} -> 1.`}
```

The link to the training data is  [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xsjxvqwds4122d/traningData.m?dl=0). 
Any suggestion on how to run classification without crashing?

Note: I am using version 11.3 on Win.

Comment: You are missing a comma, and Classify expects integer targets, otherwuse use Predict.

Comment: Hi @M.R. yes, it is my typo with the comma. Unfortunately, I have to disagree with you. It is written, in the description of the function that "Classify can be used on many types of data, including numerical...". Additionally, when I take a small training set, the Classify run correctly.

Comment: ok then post your full set with CloudPut or Dropbox and we can try to help you.

Comment: @M.R. I edited the question

Comment: Do you know offhand what if anything correlates with the crash? Are you doing other things at the time, either with kernels or the UI?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The first time the function crash, I thought that It was correlated with what I was doing, so the next time I did nothing. Unfortunately the function crash again.

Comment: By "I did nothing" do you mean "I sat still, not even moving the mouse, barely daring to breathe"? I ask because I am wondering specifically whether the crash correlated with mouse/cursor movement.

Comment: My screen goes "sleep", so I'm pretty sure I moved the mouse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I turned off the progress reporting of the classify function.  the classification process finished running without crash

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "RandomForest", TrainingProgressReporting -> None
];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
trainingData = {{{0.2443901294459203`, 0.6339894544265186`, 
      0.348376166232641`, 0.6205766754715589`, 0.6949430713884377`, 
      0.09981477603065425`, 0.2652380125320035`, 0.7326739707331305`, 
      0.33572175175325736`, 
      0.15215974016395206`}, {0.40877022570675847`, 
      0.5013459204618054`, 0.18091097996572647`, 0.9841680784952942`, 
      0.46040777479106754`, 0.9721054020948912`, 0.7980120864921296`, 
      0.985753996194227`, 0.36559491598469984`, 
      0.2578547049404678`}} -> 
    0 , {{0.033860045146726865`, 110.`, 3.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
      0.13636363636363635`, 0.9766334638696152`, 3.`, 
      1972.`}, {0.035211267605633804`, 177.`, 8.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
      0.0903954802259887`, 0.9766334638696152`, 3.`, 1145.`}} -> 1};

c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "RandomForest"]
```

[image]